# How to get --suite Parameter?

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

I would like to get `--suite` parameter. E.g.:

```
protractor conf.js --suite=foo
```

I would like to get `'foo'` in my test case. E.g.:

```
it ('Sent parameter', function() {
    consol.log('Suite is:' + ...);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config){ 
       console.log(config.suite)
});
```

Refer http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getProcessedConfig for addition info.

Comment: how to get the value of that foo from protractor.config.js?? like the exact path?? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nodejs' `process` module to obtain all command arguments by `process.argv`.

I have an `cli.params.js` to handle command arguments and return an object.

```
// cli.params.js
/**
 * get parameters value from command line,
 */
var default_processor = function(value) {
    return value ? value.trim() : value;
};

exports.process = function(options) {
    var params = options && options.default || {};
    var processor = options && options.processor || {};

    process.argv.slice(3).forEach(function(arg) {
        var flag = arg.split('=')[0];
        var value = arg.split('=')[1];
        var name = flag.replace('--', '');

        if (processor[name]) {
            processor[name](value, params);
        } else {
            params[name] = default_processor(value);
        }
    });

    return params;
};
```

How to use the `cli.params.js`

```
// protractor conf.js
var params = require('./cli.params.js').process();
console.log('suite: '+ params.suite) // smoke
console.log('env: '+ params.env) // dev
console.log('abc: '+ params.abc) // 123

// if you want to access params across scripts, you can make it as global
global.params = params

exports.config = {

    capabilities: {},

    seleniumAddress: '',

    framework: 'custom',
    ...
};

// spec.js
it ('Sent parameter', function() {
    console.log('Suite is:' + global.params.suite);
});
```

Pass-in parameter in cmd line:  
 `protractor conf.js --suite=smoke --env=dev --abc=123`

Example of passing options into `cli.params.js` process():

```
var options= {
    // set default/omit value
    default: {
        device: 'desktop',
        browser: 'chrome'
    },
    // set customize processor for certain argument, rather than the default processor
    // defined in cli.params.js
    processor: {
        'cucumberOpts.tags': function(value, params) {
            params.tags = value;
        }
    }
};
```

// cmd line 
`protractor conf.js --suite=smoke --cucumberOpts.tags=@smoke`

```
var params = require('./cli.params.js').process(options);
console.log('suite: '+ params.suite) // smoke
console.log('device: '+ params.device) // desktop, even not specify in cmd line
console.log('browser: '+ params.browser) // chrome, even not specify in cmd line
console.log('tags : '+ params.tags ) // @smoke, 
// with the customize processor in options, 
// we can use params.tags, rather than use params['cucumberOpts.tags'] to get tags values
```

Comment: Thanks for this module but 'options' is omited and generate an error. What is the value of 'options' ? ;-)

Comment: I updated the code line `var params = options && options.default || {};` and `var processor = options && options.processor || {};` in cli.params.js, it should also work now if 'options' is omited.  Please try again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the community Yong ! It works perfectly !